# Is there a way to use console.time at a less verbose log level?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have some code that uses [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) to time some events, i.e.:

```
console.time("my-timer");
doSomething();
doSomethingElse();
doOneLastThing();
console.timeEnd("my-timer");
```

I'd like to make it so that this output is not plainly visible in the JS console, unless you're viewing logs at the Verbose level.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this. `console.debug` is the only console logging method that can be hidden by disabling `Verbose`.

Comment: There's also `console.info` that can be hidden separately